Failure when creating Excel with OLEDB on Linux
I'm trying to connect to an Excel file which exists on an ubuntu server (not local).
The file is already there on the server.
The file path is:
string filePath = @"\\serverIP\fileName.xlsx";

The connection string is:
string connectionString = $@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={filePath};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;'";

I'm trying this :
string DataSource = @"\\serverIP\fileName.xlsx";

public static void botEdit(string editString,string DataSource,int x)
{
    try
    {
        OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand();
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection($"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source ={DataSource};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;'");

        con.Open();
        com.Connection = con;
        com.CommandText = editString;

        com.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if (x > 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Done");
        }

        con.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}

The problem is when I try  to connect the file I get the error

Failure creating file


There's no OLEDB on Linux and even on Windows you'd have to install a driver whose bitness (32/64-bit) matches your application's. You don't need OLEDB to create Excel files anyway you can use one of the multiple libraries that create real Excel files directly like EPPlus, ClosedXML, SylvanXlsx. Some of them have more features, some are faster and none require installing any drivers

This will never run on Linux and even on Windows, there are far better solutions. What you posted tries to use an OLEDB driver. There's no OLEDB on Linux. Even on Windows, the installed driver must match the bitness (32/64-bit) of the application.
There are many libraries that can create Excel files with features that aren't possible with the OLEDB driver.
On one end, full features libraries like EPPlus or ClosedXML can load data from lists or query results in just a couple of lines, format the resulting tables, create pivot tables and charts, with just a few lines of code, eg :
This is an example using EPPlus:
var myList = GetList();

using(var package = new ExcelPackage(@"c:\temp\myWorkbook.xlsx"))
{
    var sheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];
    var table=sheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromCollection(myList, TableStyles.Medium3, true);

    package.Save();
}

And this uses ClosedXML:
var data = new List<object[]>
{
    new object[] { "Cheesecake", 14 },
    new object[] { "Medovik", 6 },
    new object[] { "Muffin", 10 }
};

using var wb = new XLWorkbook();
var ws = wb.AddWorksheet();
ws.Cell("B3").InsertData(data);
wb.SaveAs("Demo-Bulk-Insert-Data-Enumerable.xlsx");

On the other end, libraries like Sylvan.Data.Excel are very fast, use very little memory but don't allow any formatting. Creating an Excel file is still easy though :
using var edw = ExcelDataWriter.Create("data.xlsx");
DbDataReader dr = GetQueryResults("UserReport");
edw.Write(dr, "UserReport");


ok I get it thank you so much .... so I can create an excel file then update it and delete from it by using EPPlus or ClosedXML .... right ?

Yes. Check each library's documentation. You can use those libraries even in Blazor WASM, something else OLEDB can't do

Thank you ill try it and let you know

Hi again ... I'm so sorry but I have an error say "The network path was not found"
My Path is like : @"\serverIP\home\data\customers.xlsx";

Any help for this please ?

You can't use a Windows path on Linux. For starters, the path separator is the forward slash (/) not the backslash (). Second, you need to mount the remote folder as a Linux folder using eg cifs or samba

Thank you so much indeed .... its working correctly
